# Capistrano "Press [Enter] to start a shell" on shell login

Tags: shell, capistrano

I'm trying to use capistrano to deploy on a shared host. However the ssh connection seems not to be standard, when I connect with the terminal, it asks me to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue, and this seems to prevent Capistrano from working. Here's the console output:

```
Asking for console, please wait
Connected

Grabbing terminal
Ok
Press [Enter] to start a shell

hosting-user@paas_12345:~$
```

Any idea on how I could hack Capistrano to press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key just after login? Or at least some ideas about what this strange terminal technology is?

Comment: I'd guess the login shell for the user is set to a wrapper script that prints this prompt and then enters the "real" shell (e.g., bash). Can you change the login shell for your user account?

Comment: Yeah, seems like this. No I can't change it, it's a shared hosting.

Comment: Does `ssh host bash -i` work any better? Maybe `/bin/bash` or `/usr/bin/bash` or `/usr/local/bin/bash`.

Comment: What do you mean? To connect from the terminal or with Capistrano? It works with ssh `user@host` from the terminal. I tried to connect with `ssh user@host bash -i` like you said, and it  says `exec request failed on channel 0`.

Comment: I have the same problem with gandi.net's ssh console.. don't know how to quit lol... (except closing the terminal window)